# why is max() printing the wrong amount?

Tags: python, key, max

```
list = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
        ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
         ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

print(len(max(list[0])))
```

Output: 7

why is the output 7 and not 8?

when i modify the print statement to:

```
print(len(max(list[0], key = len)))
```

it works. I dont understand why. I hope someone can help me out.

thanks

Comment: Strings are compared lexicographically by default.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask] from the [tour]. "Teach me this basic language feature" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a _specific_ question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the max function returns the string with the highest value, ordered alphabetically.
Which is "oranges", whose length is 8.

When you provide the key as a second parameter, it compares strings by their length and not alphabetically.

Comment: Thanks! hugs and kisses <3

Answer (score 0):

Because max(list[0]) equals to 'oranges' and len('oranges') equals to 7.